# Pass 2 tables as parameters inside cursor

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm basically trying to execute the same procedure on multiple columns of some tables. I have the procedure, and the cursor statements that access each column, but I cannot pass my tables to the cursor as variables:

Code:

```
DECLARE @columnName varchar(200),
 @Table1 TABLE(
        [Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [Value1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Value2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Value3] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
    ),
 @Table2 TABLE(
        [Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [Value1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
        [Value2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Value3] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
    )
INSERT @Table1 EXEC ProcedureThatAddsData;
INSERT @Table2 EXEC ProcedureThatAddsData;
DECLARE col_cursor CURSOR FOR   

select c.name from sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id where t.name = 'MySpecificTable'

OPEN col_cursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor   
INTO @columnName  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    PRINT @columnName
    --BEGIN BODY
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)


    set @sql = '
    INSERT INTO MySavedDifferencesTable
    select t1.Code, t1.Name, t1.'+ @columnName +' as OldValue, t2.'+ @columnName +' as NewValue
    from '+@Table1+' t1
    join '+@Table2+' t2
        on  t1.Code = t2.Code
        and t1.Name = t2.Name
        WHERE ISNULL(t1.' + @columnName +','') != ISNULL(t2.' + @columnName +','')
    ';
    exec (@sql)



    --end BODY
    FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor   
    INTO @columnName
END   
CLOSE col_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE col_cursor;
```

How can I make this procedure to work. The column selection in cursor is working, so `@columnName` will iterate through all the columns present in `MySpecificTable`, but I'm having trouble passing the 2 table variables inside the cursor(for loop?).

Edit:

This is the part that I'm trying to add to my cursor:

```
@Table1 TABLE(
            [Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
            [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
            [Value1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
            [Value2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
            [Value3] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
        ),
     @Table2 TABLE(
            [Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
            [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
            [Value1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
            [Value2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
            [Value3] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
        )
    INSERT @Table1 EXEC ProcedureThatAddsData;
    INSERT @Table2 EXEC ProcedureThatAddsData;
```

Either declare temporary table variables and insert data into them inside the cursor, or somehow pass outside already full of data temporary tables inside the cursor.

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question..

Comment: [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server] are two completely different products. Please only tag for the product you're working with, which I suspect is the latter.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to create a temporary table

```
-- check if temporary table already exists
    -- if not create it
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NULL
    begin
    --table with same columns as snapshot table to insert current data
    --MyTempTable
        CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable(
        [Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,..
    )
    end

    --remove old data if it exists from the temporary MyTempTable table
    delete from #MyTempTable;
    --insert the current data into the temporary MyTempTable table
    INSERT #SSDEStudySpecific EXEC procThatinsertsData;
```

And now I updated the sql that gets executed inside of my cursor like:

```
set @sql = '
    INSERT INTO MySavedDifferencesTable
    select t1.Code, t1.Name, t1.'+ @columnName +' as OldValue, t2.'+ @columnName +' as NewValue
    from '+#MyTempTable1+' t1
    join SomeSystemTable t2
        on  t1.Code = t2.Code
        and t1.Name = t2.Name
        WHERE ISNULL(t1.' + @columnName +','') != ISNULL(t2.' + @columnName +','')
    ';
```